# Getting an error with Interstitial Ads (iAd and Spritekit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, iad, interstitial

I keep getting an error within this section of code:

```
// Interstitial iAd
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
    // Check if already requesting ad
    if (requestingAd == NO) {
        interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        interstitial.delegate = self;
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
        [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdREQUEST");
        requestingAd = YES;
    }
}

-(void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    interstitial = nil;
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAd didFailWithERROR");
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidLOAD");
    if (interstitialAd != nil && interstitial != nil && requestingAd == YES) {
        //[interstitial presentFromViewController:self];
        //[interstitial presentInView:self.view] // I get an error on this line
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidPRESENT");
        if (interstitial.loaded) {
            [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation]; //I also get an error on this line too
        }
    }
}

-(void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    interstitial = nil;
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidUNLOAD");
}

-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    interstitial = nil;
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidFINISH");
}
```

Its something to do with this particular line:

```
[self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
```

This is the error I'm getting and I have no idea what this line needs changing to so that the error stops:

```
-[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146e241a0
```

Ive gotten this error in the past when working with the same sort of code, it usually appears when I start trying to implement interstitial ads. I seem to be having a lot of trouble trying to implement interstitial ads and I have read a lot of tutorials. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong :( can someone please help?

Regards,

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setShowsFPS:` is a method on `SKView`, but not on `UIView`.

Although I don't see the cause in the code you posted, the error means that a `UIView` instance is being passed to a method that expects an `SKView`. Set an exception breakpoint to try to figure out where. It's possible that it isn't your code that's triggering the call.

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude! What do you mean by "It's possible that it isn't your code that's triggering the call." what else could it be? also do you happen to have any source code of sprite kits using interstitials? I'm having so much trouble with this and its driving me crazy xD

Comment: Somebody is calling `-setShowsFPS:` (perhaps in the form `view.showsFPS = ...`). Do you do that anywhere in your entire project? If so, temporarily add an `NSAssert([myview isKindOfClass:[SKView class]])` to track it down. And if you never call that, you should suspect the code you can't see. Have you tried an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Yeah it is called because it is a Sprite kit project so it calls it by default:

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = NO;
    skView.showsNodeCount = NO; 
    skView.showsPhysics = NO;
    
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;
    
    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;   
    
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size;
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

Comment: Set a breakpoint right before that `skView.showsFPS = NO` call. Make sure that `skView` really is an `SKView` and not just a plain old `UIView`.

Comment: ok I inserted a break point and it stopped on that line but I don't know what else you want? if you put my comment /\ into Xcode it should look a bit more clear.

Comment: In the debugger, please do a "po self.view". How is the skView being created? Is it in a storyboard? If so, check in the class inspector and make sure you've changed its class from the default/greyed out UIView to SKView.

Comment: Ah, get rid of the cast: `SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view`. Make it just `SKView *skView = self.view`. A cast will just mask the problem, deferring the crash to runtime instead of catching the problem at compile time.

Comment: Ok I have removed the cast and before I have ran it I'm getting a yellow warning which is "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SKView *' with an expression of type 'UIView' " and when I run it I get the same error about the setShowFPS error from before

Comment: So that's what I was telling you in the first place. You are passing in a plain old `UIView`. Casting, or telling the compiler that it's something else, won't make it the something else. How is `self.view` being created?

Comment: Im just using the default setup that is provided when I created a new sprite kit project in Xcode. If you create a new project you might understand what I mean? Is there somewhere else can talk like a chatroom or Skype or something? Thanks for your help so far dude you are the only person thats actually tried to help me so far :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94136/discussion-between-user2876115-and-hal-mueller).

Comment: rdar://23382309 thanks to Hal I have managed to work out the problem a little more. and we have gotten it down to the following error: -[UIView setShowsFPS:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146e241a0 and after some testing we have realised that the project still thinks we are using a UIView when we are really using an SKView. If there are any Apple engineers present I would really appreciate your help

Comment: The class of the view in the storyboard was set to SKView, as is the case in Apple's standard SpriteKit Game template. However, it was being instantiated as a UIView (verified through LLDB), not an SKView. Was never able to figure out why, but adding a subview, which _is_ an SKView, solved it.